# how ti fix "could not spawn langauge tool" error?

Tags: include, pic, mplab, mov

```
include "P16F84A.inc"
 cblock 0x33
 V1
 V2
 V3
 endc
 movlw 3
 movwf V1
 movlw 4
 movwf V2
 movf V1,W
 addwf V2 , W
 movf V2,0
 movwf V3
 end
```

> Clean: Deleting intermediary and output files. Clean: Done. Executing:
> "C:\walaa\test.asm" /q /p16F84A "test.asm" /l"test.lst" /e"test.err"
> Could not spawn langauge tool.  Check command-line options.  (193)
> BUILD FAILED: Fri Dec 04 16:29:59 2020

Comment: It looks like the command line in your makefile is missing the actual assembler command. Or it is trying to execute `C:\walaa\test.asm` as if it is the assembler, when in fact it is the file to be assembled. Have a look at Project Properties in MPLAB. There should be a setting there which specifies the name of your assembler. (This all assumes that you do have an assembler installed on your system).

Comment: Provide more info about your IDE. What version of MPLAB you are using? Do you locate your source files in the project directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Original Poster does not include enough information to know for certain.

That aside, this kind of question about Microchips MPLABX has become common recently because support for the MPASMWIN assembler has been removed from MPLAX v5.40 and later.

The MPASMWIN tool chain cannot be added to these versions of the MPLABX IDE.

MPASMWIN support is present in MPLABX v5.35, the last version it was available.

The only tool chain for PIC 8-bit assembly language projects is pic-as(v2.xx).

This tool chain is part of the XC8 v2.3x C compiler installation.

Note: The pic-as(v2.3x) tool chain does not seem to be installed by default when the XC8 compiler is installed. In most cases the IDE requires the user to manually install this tool chain. That you may need to do this step is not documented by Microchip.

It would seem that Microchip's attitude is that if you are smart enough to use assembly language with obsolete controllers you should be smart enough to figure out how to install the tool chain without step by step instructions.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have `MPLAB` installed in the windows folder and the asm, linker and header are installed in root `C:`. MPLAB cannot find them.